# Textbooks on quantum field theory for Mathematicians

Tags: book-recommendation, quantum-field-theory

I'm a math undergraduate student, I'm interested in mathematical physics, and I want to
learn quantum field theory, string theory, and topological order in the future.  Can you recommend some textbooks on quantum field theory for mathematicians? I have already taken the courses of differential geometry, PDE, analysis, and abstract algebra and I want to study the rigorous mathematical structure of quantum field theory.

Comment: Etingof's lecture notes [Geometry and Quantum Field Theory](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-238-geometry-and-quantum-field-theory-fall-2002/) give a very nice mathematical treatment of perturbative quantum field theory.

Comment: M . Talagrand, *What is Quantum Field Theory?: A First Introduction for Mathematicians.* 2022.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Folland, who wrote one of the most popular measure theory books, also wrote a book called [Quantum Field Theory: A Tourist Guide for Mathematicians](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821847058).

The book [Electricity and Magnetism for Mathematicians: A Guided Path from Maxwell's Equations to Yang Mills](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107435161) by Garrity is also great.

Answer (score 3):

The book by Folland mentioned above is probably the most popular QFT textbook for mathematicians. There is also a similar book that was published only recently:
[*What is a Quantum Field Theory* by Michel Talagrand.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/what-is-a-quantum-field-theory/899688E515D7E05AAA88DB08325E6EAE)

Personally, I haven't fully read this book yet, so I cannot comment on the quality of the book (which can be very different from person to person). However, here is a [Comment of this book by Peter Woit.](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/wordpress/?p=12819) One thing he said seems very interesting to me:

> Like many mathematicians, Talagrand tried to learn about quantum field theory first from physics textbooks, which tend to avoid any precise definition of even the basics of the subject. He soon found what was the best source for someone looking for more precision, Gerald Folland’s 2008 Quantum Field Theory: A Tourist Guide for Mathematicians. Folland’s book is extremely good, but also extremely terse. In 325 pages it covers more carefully the material of an old-style QFT book such as Schweber’s 900 page or so An Introduction to Relativistic Quantum Field Theory from 1961. Talagrand is covering much the same material, but with 742 pages to work with he is able (unlike Folland) to work out many topics in full detail, providing something previously unavailable anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

To learn QFT, you must must have some bacgrounds on standard quantum mechanics. As a beginner, I recommand you the book [No-Nonsense-Quantum-Field-Theory-Student-Friendly]
([https://www.amazon.com/No-Nonsense-Quantum-Field-Theory-Student-Friendly/dp/3948763011](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3948763011))
by Jakob Schwichtenberg.